# Bringing my laptop from the EU to UK tax free

Tags: uk, eu

Shortly I will leave from the UK to the EU, bringing with me my laptop which I purchased here in the UK.

When I go back to the UK, do I need to declare my laptop?

I have purchased it years ago in the UK for a bigger price than the one allowed by the personal allowance sum (390£).

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are moving (i.e. you are currently long term resident in the EU and will become a long term resident in the UK), or just travelling there for a short period of time, or something else? As you are inquiring just about the laptop I would think the latter. As long as you take it back out of the UK and it’s obviously not new you don’t need to declare it or pay tax on it.

Comment: What you will need is (or was) called a **Information Certificate INF 3**. This is a form that you must fill out and togeather with the laptop show it to customs before you leave the UK. This verifies that you are taking this particular laptop out of the UK so that when you return no duty needs to be paid (done often with expensive goods). See: [Pay less import duty and VAT when re-importing goods to the UK - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/pay-less-import-duty-and-vat-when-re-importing-goods-to-the-uk-and-eu)

Comment: @MarkJohnson PLEASE make that an answer.

Comment: @CGCampbell Sorry, to late. Will answer if reopened.

Comment: If the OP would clarify his residence status, then the relative (abite complicated) INF3 method would be the most effective to avoid this problem, which is not meantioned in the other question. This seems to be still true for the UK.